# Contour Deformation in a Conformal Field Theory

Tags: reference-request, mathematical-physics, contour-integration, operator-algebras, conformal-field-theory

Consider the discussion on [page 77 of James Lepowsky and Haisheng Li's Introduction to Vertex Operator Algebras and Their Representations](https://books.google.com/books?id=bB3UBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA77&lpg=PA77&dq=operator%20product%20expansion%20contour%20integration&source=bl&ots=OQppEPXNkH&sig=OwEOSS9hB9Zi_dKIki5kpG0qUZg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiMpdiimMDUAhUFbD4KHcd-AQIQ6AEIRDAF#v=onepage&q=operator%20product%20expansion%20contour%20integration&f=false). In particular, the authors state that

> The operator product expansion notation...suggests the use of the contour integration technique...and in fact in the conformal field theory literature, this contour-deformation technique is indeed often used in conjunction with the operator product expansion.

I am looking for further references that discuss that connect this contour deformation with the operator product expansion. In particular, **how does deformation of the contour depend upon whether or not we are dealing with a conformal field theory?** Any explanation or reference would be appreciated.